# Why would 0042 sound 34 to int?

Tags: java

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int rishav = 42;
    System.out.println(rishav);
}
```

this gives 42, but the below gives 34 :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int rishav =0042;
    System.out.println(rishav);
}
```

If I need to transform an integer to trim its leading zeros, what do I do, most feasible.

Comment: Because numbers starting with 0 are parsed as octal numbers, not decimal ones.

Comment: Also a number doesn't have leading 0s (it doesn't make sense as a concept), but a String does.